# How to create a table in SeaORM

Tags: sea-orm

I'm trying to see how the [TableCreateStatement](https://docs.rs/sea-query/0.20.0/sea_query/table/struct.TableCreateStatement.html) should be called and where in my code it should live. Looking at the documentation no idea really.

I see I can create a table manually with:

```rust
let stmt = sea_query::Table::create()
        .table(super::post::Entity)
        .if_not_exists()
        .col(
```

but I already have copy-pasted together a `pub struct Model` and I would like to not repeat myself there.

Answer (score 1):

After hunting together through some documentation, this checks out:

```rust
let backend = conn.get_database_backend();
let schema = Schema::new(backend);
let table_create_statement = schema.create_table_from_entity(FoursquareGmapsMappings);
let table_create_result = conn.execute(backend.build(&table_create_statement)).await;
```